# Logging into linkedin

Tags: python, python-requests

I was just trying a simple POST using Linkedin

```
client = requests.Session()
URL = 'https://www.linkedin.com/uas/login-submit'
login_information = {
    'session_key':'login_email_address',
    'session_password':'password',
}

client.post(URL, data=login_information)
```

However I'm getting this as a response

```
Request Error
We’re sorry, there was a problem with your request. Please make sure you have cookies enabled and try again.

Or follow this link to return to the home page.
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Code worked for me on Python 2.7.3.

Comment: im on 2.7.2, how do I upgrade to 2.7.3?

Comment: [Download page](https://www.python.org/download)? It depends on your OS, but there are guides out there.

Comment: are you just showing a 200 response or are you actually looking at the data that's returned and seeing that you are logged in?

Answer (score 1):

I think it's not that easy to log in LinkedIn with a simple POST. Try this:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# Get login form
URL = 'https://www.linkedin.com/uas/login'
session = requests.session()
login_response = session.get('https://www.linkedin.com/uas/login')
login = BeautifulSoup(login_response.text)

# Get hidden form inputs
inputs = login.find('form', {'name': 'login'}).findAll('input', {'type': ['hidden', 'submit']})

# Create POST data
post = {input.get('name'): input.get('value') for input in inputs}
post['session_key'] = 'username'
post['session_password'] = 'password'

# Post login
post_response = session.post('https://www.linkedin.com/uas/login-submit', data=post)

# Get home page
home_response = session.get('http://www.linkedin.com/nhome')
home = BeautifulSoup(home_response.text)
```

This is code what I tried before and it worked. Tell me if there is any problem.

Answer (score 1):

I got it to work. Wasn't getting a csrf token. This works

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from unidecode import unidecode

client = requests.Session()

HOMEPAGE_URL = 'https://www.linkedin.com'
LOGIN_URL = 'https://www.linkedin.com/uas/login-submit'

html = client.get(HOMEPAGE_URL).content
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
csrf = soup.find(id="loginCsrfParam-login")['value']

# print soup.find(id="loginCsrfParam-login")

login_information = {
    'session_key':'username',
    'session_password':'password',
    'loginCsrfParam': csrf,
}

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.8; rv:31.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/31.0'}

client.post(LOGIN_URL, headers=headers, data=login_information)
```